How to find the minimum sum of products expression from a two variable truth table with only one 0?
I am looking for a minimum sum of products expression from this truth table:



A
B
f




0
0
1


1
0
0


1
1
1


0
1
1



From my understanding, I can create the minimum sum of products expression from the rows resulting in a 0. Since, we only have one 0, the resulting expression would be:
f(A,B) = A + B`
However, this expression cannot be verified on the truth table.
Did I misunderstand the concept of creating the minimum sum of products expression from a truth table?

It is in fact $A'+B$.

Thank you for your answer. I understand that your answer is correct. However, could you explain how to derive this solution from the truth table using the rules for creating a minimum product of sums? As far as I know, this involves looking at the rows that result in 0, combining these terms using the OR operator, and then multiplying all the resulting sums. @Jean Marie

It's probably overkill but you could draw a 2-variable Karnaugh map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#2-variable_map_examples. (Indeed, you'll find that your case is listed among those shown.)

The three cases where $f$ is true in the given truth table can be encoded as the non-minimal sum-of-products $f=A'B'+AB+A'B$. To make this easier to simplify, note that $A'B=A'B+A'B$ is tautologically true. Then we can regroup to get
$$f=A'B'+A'B+AB+A'B=A'(B'+B)+(A+A')B=A'+B$$
(Other choices of terms to "duplicate" result in the forms $f=A'B'+B=A'+AB$, which while valid are not simpler. An advantage of a Karnaugh map in this context is that it makes it visually obvious which products should be duplicated.)
Alternatively, suppose we look at $f'$ instead. Then by inspection $f'=AB'$, which per De Morgan's laws negates back to $f=A'+B$.
